# Android Method MKCOL, http, addHeader,

Tags: java, android, httpclient, webdav

```
- (FMWebDAVRequest*) createDirectory {
if (!_endSelector) {
    _endSelector = @selector(requestDidCreateDirectory:);
}

NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:_url];

[req setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[req setTimeoutInterval:60 * 5];

[req setHTTPMethod:@"MKCOL"];


if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"skipMKCOLContentType"]) {
    [req setValue:@"application/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
}

[self sendRequest:req];

return self;
```

This code i use for iPhone, i write WebDav client for both platforms
But i don't know how to implement MKCOL for android, that what i do
MKCOL it's WebDav method to create path, any ideas ?

```
HttpPut request = new HttpPut();
    request.addHeader("", "MKCOL /test879797 HTTP/1.1");
    request.addHeader("Host","myserver:port");
    request.addHeader("Authorization","Basic YWRtaW46MTIzNDU2");
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the following code:

```
public class HttpMkCol extends HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
{
    public static final String METHOD_NAME = "MKCOL";
    public HttpMkCol(String url)
    {
        this(URI.create(url));
    }
    public HttpMkCol(URI url)
    {
        this.setURI(url);
    }
    @Override
    public String getMethod()
    {
        return METHOD_NAME;
    }
}
```

The original source:
https://github.com/lookfirst/sardine
HttpMkCol.java

Answer (score 0):

> HttpPut request = new HttpPut();

`MKCOL` is not `PUT`.

Apache HttpClient does not directly support WebDAV. You are welcome to experiment with creating your own custom subclass of `org.apache.http.message.AbstractHttpMessage` to implement the `MKCOL` verb.

Or, you can see if somebody else created WebDAV extensions to Apache HttpClient.

Or, you can find another WebDAV client library for Java and see if it runs on Android.